A probability involving areas in a random pentagram inscribed in a circle: Is it really just $\frac12$?
This question was posted at MSE but was not answered.

The vertices of a pentagram are five uniformly random points on a circle. The areas of three consecutive triangular "petals" are $a,b,c$. The petals are randomly chosen, but they must be consecutive, either clockwise or anticlockwise.

A simulation of $10^7$ such random pentagrams yielded a proportion of $0.5000179$ satisfying $a^2<bc$.

Is the following conjecture true: $P(a^2<bc)=\frac{1}{2}$

Remarks
Note that the three petals must be consecutive. Calling the areas of consecutive petals $a,b,c,d,e$, simulations suggest that:

$P(a^2<bd)\approx0.468$
$P(a^2<be)\approx0.505$
$P(a^2<cd)\approx0.460$

Curiously, the probability that seems to equal $\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. $P(a^2<bc)$, does not involve a symmetrical arrangement of three petals.
As for other random star polygons $\{\frac{n}{2}\}$ inscribed in a circle, simulations suggest that

Star polygon $\left\{\frac{6}{2}\right\}$: $P(a^2<bc)\approx0.505$.
Star polygon $\{\frac{7}{2}\}$: $P(a^2<bc)\approx0.504$.

I used the shoelace formula to calculate the areas of the triangular petals.
One might expect that a probability of $\frac12$ should have an intuitive explanation, but sometimes probabilities of $\frac12$ are hard to explain.
Underlying reason?
Simulations suggest that the random pentagram/pentagon shape is teeming with probabilities of powers of $\frac12$. In the following diagram, the letters represent areas of the regions.


$P(g+b+h<a+f+c)\overset{?}{=}\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$
$P(g+h<f)\overset{?}{=}\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}$
$P((g+a+k)(h+c+i)>(b+f+e+d+j)^2)\overset{?}{=}\color{red}{\frac{1}{8}}$
$P(\text{each region with area $g,b,f,l$ contains the centre of the circle})=\color{red}{\frac{1}{16}}$ (proved)
$P(\text{areas of petals increase going around once, clockwise or anticlockwise})\overset{?}{=}\color{red}{\frac{1}{32}}$

I am not asking to prove these other probability claims. I am presenting them to suggest that there may be an underlying reason why the pentagram has probabilities of powers of $\frac12$, which may be relevant to my conjecture. These simulations make me more inclined to believe that my conjecture is true, but I could be wrong.

Petals may be permuted arbitrarily  and this is measure-preserving, why is not probability that their areas increase equal to 10/120=1/12?

@FedorPetrov Apparently, the geometry of the pentagram and circle affects the probabilities of sequences of petal areas. Simulations also suggest that the probability that the two largest petals are next to each other, is approximately $0.27$ (not $1/2$).

Hmmm, are petals bounded by a circle and a chord, or is this something different?

@FedorPetrov Each petal is a triangle, bounded by three chords.

Ah! With one vertex at a circle?

@FedorPetrov Yes, each petal has one vertex on the circle.

Just curious: is not it true that if we inscribe five generic squares in the circle, then between 1024 pentagons with vertices taken one from each square exactly 32 have cyclically monotonic petals?

Simulations with larger sample-size ($10^{10}$) suffice to effectively show that $p:=P(a^2<bc)<\frac{1}{2}$. Specifically, a $99.9%$ CI for $p$ is $0.49994 \pm 0.00002 = (0.49992, 0.49996)$. (I've posted this at the original question on MathSE.)

would you describe more precisely how the three triangles  are chosen?

@PietroMajer Choose five uniformly random points on a circle. Then choose one of those points at random, and label it $P_0$. Then, going anticlockwise from $P_0$, label the other four points $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$. Then draw five chords: $P_0 P_2, P_2 P_4, P_4 P_1, P_1 P_3, P_3 P_0 $, thus forming a pentagram. The pentagram consists of a central pentagon and five triangular petals. There are five ways to choose three consecutive petals. Choose one of those ways at random, and label the areas of those petals, going clockwise, $a,b,c$.

The question has been answered at the original MSE question. (A simulation with a larger sample size shows that a $99.9$% confidence interval for the probability is $0.49994\pm0.00002$.)

$-1$. the question has not been answered.

@mathworker21 Fair enough, but the answer works for me.

I worry the linked answer relies on the prng having perfectly random properties. I would at least try some different prngs to check you get the same result.
